# iTextSharp generating InvalidCastException on htmlWorker.Parse

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, .net

When attempting to turn a GridView into a PDF I am getting an InvalidCastException when using iTextSharp on the line

```
htmlWorker.Parse(stringReader)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I searched and everyone seems to do this the same way.
Here is the error.

Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'.

Here are my includes for iTextSharp

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Here is my code.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
}

protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=PDFDoc.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(stringWriter.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlWorker.Parse(stringReader);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Without the HTML itself its really hard to tell you what to fix. Try rendering `GridView1` again via `GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);` (don't just view source), save the output to a file and then bake that into the code. Then start deleting things from the HTML until you get the smallest amount that still causes that error and we might be able to help you more. Also, HTMLWorker is long deprecated in favor of XMLWorker, I'd really recommend giving that a shot first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter)` I had to put the following code.

```
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;    
GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Then it worked like a charm.